# ADC AD7147 Datasheet problem

Tags: adc

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7147.pdf

From the datasheet, on page 18, there is an example -

To connect CIN3 to the positive CDC input on Stage 0 use the following setting:

STAGE0_CONNECTION[6:0] = 0xFFBF

STAGE0_CONNECTION[12:7] = 0x2FFF

I am confused with the - STAGE0_CONNECTION[12:7] = 0x2FFF ; 0x2FFF = 0010111111111111

But from the SINGLE-ENDED CONNECTIONS TO THE CDC,  SE_CONNECTION_SETUP = 01: single-ended connection. For this stage, there is one CINx connected to the positive CDC input

so instead of 0x2FFF = 00**10**111111111111, it should be 0x1FFF = 00**01**111111111111

Am I right or I am mistaking something?

Thanks

Comment: That does look odd.  You might check for errata, see if you can come up with an *experiment* to verify which setting correlates with the desired result, and also contact the manufacturer's support.

Answer (score 1):

The setup bits for `CINx_CONNECTION_SETUP` and `SE_CONNECTION_SETUP` are different from each other.

The example on page 18:

`STAGE0_CONNECTION[6:0] = 0xFFBF`

`STAGE0_CONNECTION[12:7] = 0x2FFF`

is for the `CINx_CONNECTION_SETUP`, and matches Figure 29 on that page:

[image]

The bullet points on that same page are for a different section, "**SINGLE-ENDED CONNECTIONS TO THE CDC**" and are for the `SE_CONNECTION_SETUP`

[image]

This is corroborated by table 35 on page 54:

[image]

Again, note the difference between `CINx_CONNECTION_SETUP` and `SE_CONNECTION_SETUP`.

Comment: But I am talking about 'SE_CONNECTION_SETUP'. I have no problem with the 'CINx_CONNECTION_SETUP'

in the 'SE_CONNECTION_SETUP' 
according to datasheet, 01 for one CINx connected to CDC positive input

but in the example they used, 10

Comment: The example you are referring to is NOT for single ended operation.  This was my point, the example is not for the section you are using.  So, in your case, use `01`.